# Djaty - How to capture 404 errors when clicking on a corrupted route inside my angular application?

Tags: djaty

I've checked the docs and found that there are some ways to ignore a certain error but what I want to do is the opposite of this. I want to include an error that is ignored by default. For example, 404 errors when clicking on a corrupted route inside my angular application or when landing on a route that doesn't exist.

Note: I don't want to catch 404 Ajax requests. I want to catch the errors when navigating to a route - an Angular route- that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, angular will throw an unhandled exception for non existing routes. So, make sure that `Djaty.trackBug(exception)` is added to your error handler. If you don't register the `ErrorHandler` to your `AppModule`, you can create it as the following:

```
export class DjatyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(err: Error): void {
    // Calling `trackBug` to notify Djaty about all uncaught exceptions.
    Djaty.trackBug(err);
  }
}
```

And add it to `AppModule` providers

```
@NgModule({
   // ...
   providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: DjatyErrorHandler}],
   // ...
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

If you are not interested in tracking any uncaught exception - Which is not recommended - you can subscribe to `router.events` and call `Djaty.trackBug` when the event is a `NavigationError`

Ex:
Add this code to `app.component.ts`

```
this.router.events.subscribe(ev => {
  if (ev instanceof NavigationError) {
    Djaty.trackBug(ev.error);
  }
});
```